# how to update url in database

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have created a database in wordpress and inserting data dynamically as well as i want to update it but when i insert same url in text field it doesn't give me desired solution.

```
 if(isset($_POST))
 {
    //echo $_POST['url'];
    $name=xmlfeeds_select();
    $url=$_POST['url'];
    $url1=parse_url("name");
    $url2=parse_url("url");
    echo "$name";

    echo "$url";
    if($url1['host'] == $url2['host'] )
    {

        xmlfeeds_update();

    }

        xmlfeeds_insert();
```

//query for update url

```
function xmlfeeds_update(){
$x=$_POST['url'];
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->update( 
'xml_url', 
array( 
    'url' => $x,    
    'update_date' =>  current_time('mysql',1)
), 
array( 'url' => $x ), 
array( 
    '%s',   
    '%s'    
), 
array( '%s' ) 
);

}
```

Actually my problem is that when i give the same url in url field which i have already inserted in database,it checks the equality condition but when i insert different url in url field ,it doesn't perform insert query.

Please help me through this.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you defined url field as unique ?

Comment: @Barney Stinson, No i thinks my condition to check the equality of url is not working.can you please tell me what will be the right condition to check   two url value?